# Why do people write answers which give compiler warnings on my system?

Tags: discussion

Well, probably it is not the best title of my problem (it is not quite a problem), but I will try to explain it somehow. Please be gentle.

I see that more than 50% from all Answers (code in programs) here, when comes about conversions, are not correct and cannot be compiled because either they are not checked before sending or maybe just copy pasted.

To be more precise, I will give you as an example the printf Function and the way how we use it.

Here is a program which i saw it today and fits perfectly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void) {
    printf ("BITS/CHAR %d\n", CHAR_BIT);
    printf ("CHARS/SHORT %d\n", sizeof(short));
    printf ("CHARS/INT %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf ("CHARS/LONG %d\n", sizeof(long));
    printf ("CHARS/LLONG %d\n", sizeof(long long));
    putchar ('\n');

    printf ("SHORT MIN %d\n", SHRT_MIN);
    printf ("SHORT MAX %d\n", SHRT_MAX);
    printf ("INT MIN %d\n", INT_MIN);
    printf ("INT MAX %d\n", INT_MAX);
    printf ("LONG MIN %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
    printf ("LONG MAX %ld\n", LONG_MAX);
    printf ("LLONG MIN %lld\n", LLONG_MIN);
    printf ("LLONG MAX %lld\n", LLONG_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

When we try to compile it, we get:

> ```
> program.c: In function ‘main’:
> program.c:6:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
>      printf ("CHARS/SHORT %d\n", sizeof(short));
>      ^
> program.c:7:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
>      printf ("CHARS/INT %d\n", sizeof(int));
>      ^
> program.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
>      printf ("CHARS/LONG %d\n", sizeof(long));
>      ^
> program.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
>      printf ("CHARS/LLONG %d\n", sizeof(long long));
> ```

As you can see there are a lot of errors in here (easy to fix them) which for us, as beginners, it can be a challenge.

So my question is, why don't people check the code before posting here ?

EDIT:

Here is another example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    int len = 0;
    char *string = "michi";
    len = strlen(string);

    printf("Len = %d",len);
    return 0;
}
```

If i compile with **gcc -Wconversion program.c -o program** , will not work:

> ```
> program.c: In function ‘main’:
> program.c:7:15: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘size_t’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
>          len = strlen(string);
>                ^
> ```

Because of the returning of strlen Function which expects size_t, but they still use int instead of size_t. This is also often used.

Comment: Because people are sloppy and don't care for the finer details. Unfortunately.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh,  it can be, i am new in here (3 months i think) and i am not familiar with all things, but this is for me not so easy to understand why its happening  something like this.
Anyway this is a reason (because of the question int he wrong place) for me to get -1 ?

Comment: @Michi Well, that is not an excuse for not taking the [tour] and read the [ask] page  to see what actually fits here. Please take your time to read them. Just trying to point you towards the right direction, nothing else. :-)

Comment: I will read them (again) sir. I was sure that it is ok to put it in here. It is not easy to post a question here because you never know how people are treated you in here just because you are a beginner.Thank you sir.

Comment: @Michi It is not about a beginner or experienced. It is all about whether the question fits in here. Believe me, if a so called _reputed_ user had posted this question, it was certain to see the same fate. Nothing personal. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, Sir i due understand and for me there is no reason to care about reputation in here, its just about how are you treated.  I need to learn C (and when i can to help others), not to get some reputation :) .

Comment: I did not intend to point out the reputation part as a part of experience. Other than anything, a good reputation shows the associativity with this site for a reasonable amount of time to understand how things work here. and In case, you're interested in `C` part of this question, don't you think your title should have been written differently?

Comment: Please tell me a better one and i will change it, or do it your self please.

Comment: "Why do people write answers which don't compile on my system?"

Comment: @Bill Woodger Does even compile on other Systems ?

Comment: @Michi: Yes, there certainly are some.

Comment: But, do you know? Have you tried on their system? With some, you can be definite (almost definite) but not with others. If you are only interested in answers which don't work at all, anywhere (these are known as PIADWAP "platform-independent answers - don't work on any platform") then put a full-stop/period after the word "compile".

Comment: Well, this is something new for me, i tought that for unsigned it is %zu and not %d.

Comment: Are those not warnings, rather than errors?

Comment: Warnings are not errors. You asked the compiler to show warnings, which to my mind is a good thing. However, the code would run on your system, it is not failing to compile. You should mention the -Wconversions switch in your question, it makes the whole thing a lot clearer. And points to a massive (post facto) mistake in my title-suggestion :-)

Comment: Of course they are, but if we ignore them is not a problem at some point of codding ? i use also -Werror to convert them into errors.

Comment: @Michi There's a debate about whether warnings should be fixed or not. I'm on your side in the debate :-)

Comment: This means for me that you did understood my problem :)) .

Answer (score 9):

> So my question is, why don't people check the code before posting here
>   ?

Because it's not mandatory to check/compile your code before posting on SO. This is a fundamental part of the dynamics Stackoverflow system: people are allowed to post inaccurate, subjective or outright bad answers. Votes reasonably indicate how good the posts are. That's what voting system is there for.

No one is perfect here <sup>1</sup>. So you can't always expect compilable and/or accurate answers because not all answerers are subject experts on the topics they post answers.

- Downvote if the answers are wrong.
- Comment on it if you need clarification or think there could be an issue with the answer.
- Edit if you see a minor problem or inaccuracy.
- Post a new question (referring to the old question) asking what you don't understand
- etc

There are always ways to improve existing answers or get better answers.

This particular code you posted has a slight misunderstanding or lack of knowledge: To print a `size_t`, `%zu` should be used, not `%d`. I personally wouldn't downvote for this but edit the post or comment to state the same.

<sup>1</sup> That statement is not applicable to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: I saw many times that if i compile some code took from an answers with -Wconversion,  i get a lot of warnings, which it is the same story for me.

Comment: Jon Skeet I think would be more realistic about himself.

Comment: @Michi so... don't compile with `-Wconversion`? Or make the changes it suggests, which is the whole point of running with that flag.

Comment: Do you mean there are ways to try to improve an answer, or get a better one, or do you mean that answers can always be improved, so there is no definitive answer to anything?

Comment: @BillWoodger I meant that if the answers are inaccurate there are ways to improve them. Answers can be definitive for some questions (but not for all).

Comment: @jonrsharpe , Sir i just edited my Question please read it. Thank you.

Comment: @Michi you've just added another example of exactly the same thing, so I don't see why you thought re-reading would be necessary.

Comment: @BillWoodger I  probably should have used an emoticon there. It's one of the [Jon Skeet facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) :)

Answer (score 7):

You assume the poster is wrong. That could be true.

I have no solid background in C and no C/C++ compiler available at the moment so I dropped the code in the online C++ compiler: [ideone](http://ideone.com/fOhhRA).

I used the option C++14 that hints that it is using gcc-5.1

This is the result:

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3456 signal:0

BITS/CHAR 8
CHARS/SHORT 2
CHARS/INT 4
CHARS/LONG 4
CHARS/LLONG 8

SHORT MIN -32768
SHORT MAX 32767
INT MIN -2147483648
INT MAX 2147483647
LONG MIN -2147483648
LONG MAX 2147483647
LLONG MIN -9223372036854775808
LLONG MAX 9223372036854775807
```

No errors / no warnings. You can hardly blame the OP for posting an answer that works if used with a certain configuration. Your question should therefor not be:

> why don't people check the code before posting here

because if the OP used ideone the code worked/compiled. Instead ask

> Which configuration options should I use when compiling C++ code found in answers on Stack Overflow

Your other non-working example also works fine in [ideone](http://ideone.com/426U2d).

You seem to be [Barking up the wrong tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barking_up_the_wrong_tree)

Comment: In my experience, ideone quietly discards warnings if the compilation is successful. If you want to see whether some code emits a warning, you have to add a deliberate compilation error, and then you will see both errors and warnings.

Answer (score 5):

You used a compiler option that did not actually help you at all.  You can easily follow its advice and thus produce a more correct program.  It however has no effect whatsoever on the way the program works.

So now you just traded one problem for another, you are not ahead.  Arguably it is a lot worse, you discovered that you know a lot less than necessary to understand how the program works.  Not good.  Those warnings certainly did not provide any actual insight.  Using these options is a fine idea (do favor a lint tool instead), but when you use them you'll also have to deal with the exact *meaning* of the warnings that they produce.  A compiler is not up to that task by a very long shot.  It requires a massively parallel computer, the kind that hasn't yet been built.  Not otherwise hard to find, everybody has one between their ears :)

If yours is still under construction then just borrow another one.  Readily available here, just click the Ask Question button.